# Multi-column btree index & INLJ

Tags: postgresql, join, btree

I have three tables:

```
FILM(ID,TITLE)
ACTOR(ID,NAME,GENDER)
CAST(ACTOR_ID,FILM_ID,ROLE)
```

Foreign keys: ACTOR_ID, FILM_ID

And I have created a btree on columns (ACTOR_ID,FILM_ID) of CAST table.

Could I use the INLJ (index nested loop join) algorithm to make the following join?

```
...
FROM FILM,CAST
WHERE FILM.ID = CAST.FILM_ID ;
```

Comment: You'd better have an index (film_id, actor_id). And it is also advisable to have `FROM film JOIN cast ON cast.film_id = film.id` instead of using `implicit joins`.

Comment: Yes i know it is better. But would the INLJ work in my situation?

Comment: Use EXPLAIN with your specific query and let the database tell you. My **guess** is *no*.

Answer (score 2):

I very much doubt it will ever do that.  PostgreSQL doesn't yet implement index skip scans, and if it did they would only be effective if there were only a handful of different actors.

It is possible, but not very likely, to use the index for something other than an INLJ.  If the `role` field is very wide (causing the `cast` table to be much larger than the index on it), and `role` is not in your select list, and the table is kept well vacuum, then it might decide to index-only-scan the index rather than seq scan the `cast` table as part of a merge join or hash join.

(By the way, `cast` is not a valid table name as it is a reserved word)